Markdown for logic symbols
I'm looking for a Markdown guide to write symbols used in logic formulas and equations, I recently got someones e.g. $\Gamma$ ,
$$ a\ equiv b $$
but I don't know enough, e.g. "For All", "There is". I would be grateful if someone send me a good link.
By the way I see that this doesn't work here.

MathJax is not enabled on [philosophy.se]: Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?
When I would like to include one of these symbols, I copy and paste them from a page like this: https://www.symbolcopy.com/math-symbol.html
It's not convenient, but they're not often needed.

Thanks so much. Symbolcopy seems very helpful

I personally use emacs with TeX input mode. This lets me type a formula with LaTeX commands like \forall, \exists etc and it will replace with the Unicode symbols which I can then copy over to my browser.
Although, be aware that emacs is a programmer's editor with a steep learning curve. It has some really useful features you can't find anywhere else, but you'll need to learn a bunch of basics to get started with TeX input mode if you are new to the editor.
Anyway, here are a few math and logic related symbols you may copy and save somewhere for later use.
∧∨¬∃∀→⇔⊆∊∪∩≡≤≥⊢⊨
αβγΓΔδεζιηΘθϑΛλμΞξΠτπρ∇Σ∑σςΦφΨψΩω
∑∫∏∞ΘϴΩÕ(n)±∝·∂∈
⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰⁱʲᵏˡᵐⁿᵒᵖʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻᵝᵞᵟᶿᶥᵠᵡ₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₊₋₌₍₎ₐₑₕᵢⱼₖₗₘₙₒₚᵣₛₜᵤᵥₓᵦᵧᵨᵩᵪ
ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ

To write on a computer is easiest. I usually type on Android phone.

A few more common ones: ≤ ≥ ⊢ ⊨
Arrows: ←↑→↓⇒

Also subscript, superscript are better. handled by enclosing sub sup within the '<' '>' html tags. [Your subscripts appear as boxes on my phone]
